# Specific differences between similar structures:

Tags: adverbs

What are the differences between adverb structures, so much/ this much/ that much and so many/ this many/ that many? And how do I tell one from the another? How can I use them?

Thanks.

Comment: *So much* can be an adjective, pronoun, or adverb. *This/that* can be a determiner or pronoun. So this question is too broad without a context. Please provide an example(a sentence, discourse, or excerpt) so the scope can be narrower and we can give a concise answer.

Comment: so much in "thank you *so much*" indicate the amount of appreciation you want to express when you thank someone. "Thank you so much" is more emphatic than "thank you"